# Can I sign ActiveX control with root certificate?

Tags: activex, certificate, openssl, code-signing, ca

I have an ActiveX control, which is supposed to be installed at the first visit of web-page.

I have self-signed certificate, created with OpenSSL, and its child. The problem is that if I sign an activeX control with root certificate, Windows can't validate it while checking activex, even if it is installed as trusted.

It writes, that

> "A certificate's basic extension has not been observed"

and in "view certificate":

> "The certificate is not valid because one of certification authorities in the certification path does not appear to be allowed to issue certificates or this certificate cannot be used as an end-entity certificate".

If I use child certificate for signing while root certificate is in trusted, eberything is fine.

I suppose that root certificate can only sign only certificate-related stuff, not files etc, however want to be sure about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what that error message is trying to tell you is that the certificate you have generated for your key does not contain the correct certificate extensions. Code-signing requires a certificate that has been generated *for* code-signing. Other types of certificate -- e.g. those that are  generated for signing data -- are subject to less scrutiny by the CA, and so offer a lower level of security that is required for code-signing.

Your own self-signed root certificate should be set up for key-signing, and the child certificate should be set up for code signing. Then your ActiveX signature should be OK, so long as your root certificate is in the browser's trusted key store. Generally a key-signing certificate should be set up *only* for key-signing and a code-signing certificate should be set op *only* for code-signing, so you can't use these keys for any other purpose.

That solution is OK within an organization, where you can install your root key on every user's PC in advance. If you want to use your ActiveX control on a webpage on the public internet you will either have to persuade users to trust your certificate (even though they may have no good reason to do so) or you will have to buy a code-signing certificate from one of the commercial CAs whose root certificates are already known to the common browsers.

Finally, I'd **really** advise against using ActiveX controls for **anything** as they'll only be able to run on Windows, and then only if they're trusted. Most people who have any sense will have their browser's security set up to reject them. You'll have much more success producing your active content with a different technology (*e.g.* Javascript)

Comment: Thanks. Found answer by myself, but nevertheless.

Comment: How do you use OpenSSL to generate a single certificate that can be used to sign code *and* can also be stored into the Trusted Root Certificates store to allow it to validate?

Answer (score 0):

Using self-signed certificates for digitally signing your binaries pretty much goes against the [concept of using digital certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security) with programs.  The basic idea is to prove the code was created by you (authenticity) and has not been modified since you released it (integrity).  This must be done by using a signed certificate that is signed by a trusted Certificate Authority (CA).

I've answered this in a little more detail on the following question.

[creating a key and signing executable with signtool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116639/creating-a-key-and-signing-executable-with-signtool/4116687#4116687)

Comment: There are still good uses for a self-signed certificate. What if you have an internal QA environment in which executables are to be signed and tested? We have one, and our QA environment must not generate officially signed executables. It is not worth (and it is dangerous) to buy an official certificate to be used just for QA.